# Processor and RAM

Tags: memory, cpu

So, for the past couple (Around 8?) of years, I have been using a 1.6Ghz Dual-Core CPU( I know, it's terrible, I tried upgrading, but it's an AM2), with 4GB of RAM, I recently put in 4 more GB of RAM, but it doesn't / didn't seem to have much of an affect on my system overall. It may have increased performance, but not a noticeable amount.

With this, I'm wondering if a low end processor can only use a certain amount of RAM, or would it use all of the RAM like any other type of processor.

(I'm not sure this is the type of place to ask this type of question, sorry if I posted this in the wrong area!)

Comment: AM2 is an AMD socket configuration but Duo Core is an 2006-2007 Intel processor.  Unless your system was constrained by low amounts of memory its unlikely you will see any considerable performance boost.  Of course you didn't indicate if you were running a 32-bit or 64-bit operating system.

Comment: http://www.amazon.com/AMD-Athlon-512KB-Socket-Dual-Core/dp/B0016P38WU I'm pretty sure this is a good example of what type of processor I have. Dual Core? Possibly?

Comment: @Raze - You said `Duo Core` originally, I see you actually meant to a say **dual core** and I see you updated your question.  Unless you were already running a 64-bit operating system your likely to see next no performance increases. Just incase you actually did mean to say Duo Core, that particular product line, is not a 64-bit [processor](http://ark.intel.com/products/27233/Intel-Core-Duo-Processor-T2300-2M-Cache-1_66-GHz-667-MHz-FSB).

Comment: I'm pretty sure I am running on 64-bit Windows 7 Home Premium, the previous link wasn't an exact link to my processor, just an example. (They are very similar except the specs on them)

Comment: Instead of guessing, go to `Start` > right click on `Computer` > choose `Properties`. In the center of that window, under `System`, it will show you what processor, memory and system type you have. Please add those details to your question.

Comment: The 5800+ would give you some good performance push. And it is cheap. Your bottleneck is probably the HDD. Get a SSD and your system will be a LOT faster. Since this looks like a desktop, install it in addition to the HDD and move only the OS to the SSD. You can get a 120GB SSD for less than $60.

Answer (score 0):

Technically, increasing your memory has no direct impact in performance. It only means you can load more stuff at the same time. I know the SuperFetch will work better if you have a minimal of 8GB of memory, but thats another story.

Also, you won't be able to address more than 3.5GB of memory if you are using a 32-bit system, so its helpless to try.

If your CPU supports dual channel (and this feature is enabled) make sure you have two memory banks or it won't work and you will lose performance.

But ultimately, I think its time to get a new computer. Even the Raspberry Pi has more CPU power than this toaster you are piloting.